# Are there any languages designed for writing portable algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, programming-languages

Suppose I want to write a QR code reading library. It would be a single function something like this:

```
function Decode(pixels: []byte, int width, int height) -> []byte
```

I.e. it takes an image, and does lots of internal operations and produces the contents of the QR code.

I want this algorithm to be easy to use natively on lots of different platforms - Web (JS), Android (Java), iOS (Swift), Windows (C++/C#) etc.

Are there any languages that are particularly suited to this task, and allow easy compilation of code to many languages producing small clean output?

The only one I can think of is Haxe, but it doesn't have fixed-size integers, and [doesn't seem very suitable](http://blog.zame-dev.org/8-things-i-dont-like-in-haxe/). I'm looking for a more restrictive language that produces clean code (where possible).

Comment: You shouldn't underestimate an important requirement: you also need data structures. Portability for these constructs might be even harder to achieve. As far as I know, automatic code generators rarely produce "small clean output".

Comment: none, use someone else's prebuilt library for that.

Comment: Good point about data structures, but I feel that a simple list can be fairly easily translated to most languages (`Array` in JS, `vector<>` in C++, etc.). Same for maps/dictionaries. Go gets by with just those.

Answer (score 4):

For best performance you can write the code in C. Then use either SWIG to bind the library natively to other languages or cross compile on the target platform (i.e. asm.js to get javascript equivalent code).
This is an easy case since you don't have very complex data structures that need to be passed back and forth or need to call OS functions. Also for portability stick to the ISO standard as much as possible.

You can do the same trick with other languages but, as far as I know, C is the easiest one to integrate (i.e. if you want to call a java function from C you need to start an entire VM for it).

They size of integer formats are fairly well established for C.

There's no binary format that works seamlessly across different environments.

Comment: I specifically want to avoid the hassle of using C and FFIs. I want a restricted algorithm DSL that cleanly compiles to several target languages.

Comment: @Timmmm Check out SWIG! For your simple interface it should work out of the box in most cases and you should have to deal with low level-language specific APIs and other things. Will work for any language that can load a binary library at runtime (all but javascript).

Comment: That looks like it just reduces the FFI hassle a bit. I want to totally remove it by transpiling.

Answer (score 0):

1. **many nowadays (huge) apps use DLLs/OBJs for this.**

   It is far from ideal (And I hate this approach) but allows to change module versions without recompilation of the main executable which is ideal for multiple programing group cooperation. But also brings up many other issues like miss-matching versions, compatibility issues, big loading times etc. And for old huge projects also abusively/insane huge **DLL/Lib** nesting...

   For example once I was consulting on a printer firmware problem (10 years ago) and the firmware was `300+ MByte` !!! of **C++/Asm** code mostly due to insane include nesting and very poor management over the past years. The compilation time was around 15-30 minutes ... for a single **ARM MCU** chip **FLASH** ...
2. **There are "cross platform" languages like JAVA out there**

   but if the App is not written properly then it will not work properly. Have you tried to run any **JAVA** based game from phone on different platform (or even different kind of phone)? Of coarse you can forget about the speed in most cases...
3. **C++**

   I would go for **C++** not only because of speed and it is my native programming language for more then a decade but because all of the platforms I know of has compilers or cross compilers for it.

   Again you will need to learn write the code properly so it is usable between different platforms ... not using any funny stuff or exploiting undefined behavior.

   Separate App layers into:

   - **logic** (same for all platforms)
   - **OS** and **IO** related stuff (differ across platforms)
   - **gfx** (can differ across platforms but you can use **OpenGL** which is supported on most)

   And for platform dependent stuff use statements like:

   ```
   #define _target_windows

   #ifdef _target_windows
   //... do your stuff ...
   #endif

   #ifdef _target_linux
   //... do your stuff ...
   #endif

   #ifdef _target_ios
   //... do your stuff ...
   #endif
   ```

   to manage compilation across different platforms with the same source code. **C++** compilers usually define specific tokens for actual platform **OS** and compiler even version ... so you do not need to define them your self

Answer (score 0):

Such multi-backend languages exist. One effort that first crossed my mind was [Fantom](http://fantom.org). It has JVM, CLR and JS backends. Here is a [list with some other candidates](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/list-of-languages-that-compile-to-js#multitarget).

I wouldn't consider any of these languages for a serious project at the moment though.

One possible solution to the problem is to use JS (or one of the languages that compiles to JS such as TypeScript or PureScript). JS is usable on most platforms including JVM and .NET. There may be a cost in performance and productivity though.

Comment: Nice list! I don't think it is quite what I am looking for though. I want a more restrictive DSL that produces cleaner code.

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't realised you were more after a DSL.

Answer (score 0):

[Cryptol](http://www.cryptol.net) is a DSL for specifying cryptographic algorithms. Of course, more general algorithms can be specified also (e.g. included is a sudoku solver).

This seems closer to what you're looking for than my previous answer which mentioned more general purpose languages. However, if you like Cryptol, you will have to roll up your sleeves to implement the backends you're looking for.